# Woocommerce display rating if no review in product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display rating when no review available in product.

Currently display rating when at least one review available.

Thanks,
Rajesh Solanki

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_rating_html','bb_woocommerce_product_get_rating_html',10,3);
```

function bb_woocommerce_product_get_rating_html($html, $rating, $count){

```
if ( 0 == $rating ) {
    $html  = '<div class="star-rating">';
    $html .= wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count );
    $html .= '</div>';
}
return $html;
```

}